# I need a universal wrapper for all my methods without duplicating the code (C#)

Tags: c#

I have a function

```
public TOut PerformDbOperation<TIn, TOut>(Func<IDbConnection, TIn, TOut> method, TIn param1, bool withinTransaction)
{
    IDbConnection db = GetNewDbConnection();
    OpenConnection(db);
    IDbTransaction transaction = null;

    if (withinTransaction) {
        transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
    }

    try {
        TOut result = method(db, param1);
        if (withinTransaction) {
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        return result;

    }
    finally {
        if (withinTransaction) {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
        CloseConnection(db);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to modify this function, so it would be able to wrap any method, no matter if it's void or returning something or how many parameters it requires? Or do I need to write another wrapper every time I add new method with a different number of parameters?

Comment: Take a look at Aspect Oriented Programming. Here is a related article: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/patterns-practices/1443/aop-csharp-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public TOut PerformDbOperation<TOut>(Function<IDbConnection,TOut> method, bool withinTransaction)
{
    IDbConnection db = GetNewDbConnection();
    OpenConnection(db);
    IDbTransaction transaction = null;

    if (withinTransaction) {
        transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
    }

    try {
        TOut result = method(db);
        if (withinTransaction) {
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        return result;

    }
    finally {
        if (withinTransaction) {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
        CloseConnection(db);
    }
}
```

and to call the methode :

```
string s = PerformDbOperation((db) => yourMethode(db, param1, param2, param3));
```

if you also need to pass methode that doesn't return anything make an overload that uses `Action<IDbConnection>` instead of `Function<IDbConnection,TOut>`.

```
public void PerformDbOperation(Action<IDbConnection> method, bool withinTransaction)
{
     PerformDbOperation((db) => 
     {
          method(db);
          return 0;
     } 
     ,withinTransaction);  //this will call the other overload thanks to the 'return 0' stamtement
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the command pattern.

```
public interface IDbOperation<out TResult>
{
    TResult Result { get; }
    void Execute(IDbConnection connection);
}
```

Classes implementing this interface can have parameters passed through the constructor

```
public Class1 : IDbOperation<string>
{
    public Class1(int param1, double param2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public string Result { get; private set; }

    public void Execute(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        ...
        Result = ...;
    }
}

public Class2 : IDbOperation<int>
{
    public Class2(Person person)
    {
        ...
    }

    public int Result { get; private set; }

    public void Execute(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        ...
        Result = ...;
    }
}
```

The wrapper method becomes

```
public TOut PerformDbOperation<TOut>(IDbOperation<TOut> operation, bool withinTransaction)
{
    IDbConnection db = GetNewDbConnection();
    OpenConnection(db);
    IDbTransaction transaction = null;

    if (withinTransaction) {
        transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
    }

    try {
        operation.Execute(db);
        if (withinTransaction) {
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        return operation.Result;
    }
    finally {
        if (withinTransaction) {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
        CloseConnection(db);
    }
}
```

It does not need to know the parameters of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better if you implement your own `DbConnection` by applying some inheritance of an existing one. So in this case, you can have your own method that will execute some stuff, and in this method you can execute the methods of your inheritance.